# Bode curve in simulink

Tags: simulink

I try to simulate a power electronic chopper like buck or boost or any of them to get the bode plot of model. but I can't do that.in the other word I can't use bode block in simulink.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of the Simulink Control Design Toolbox, you can use [following approach](https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/gs/bode-response-of-simulink-model.html) to get the Bode plots of a Simulink model. You can find a more detailed explanation of this approach [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96917-is-there-a-bode-plot-block-in-simulink).